# Adding nodes within the two minute delay

Tags: cassandra

Hello gurus of the Cassandra universe!

I am a lowly devops engineer trying to solve for a problem I can't even clearly define and I need some insight.

Per the documentation for Cassandra (both [v.2.0](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html#task_ds_in2_qjq_gk__set-props) and [v.1.2](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html#task_ds_in2_qjq_gk__yaml-props)), when you are spinning up new nodes to join to an existing cluster you need to wait two minutes between starting each of them. There is no explanation on the reasoning for why precisely two minutes, or the consequences for not following these instructions. In talking with the team that supports Cassandra here, I have been told that it can lead to a very awkward scenario that causes nodes to not properly take ownership of data they should be responsible for (my non-db summary of what they said), which is nearly undetectable, and is not repairable (our only known fix is to build a new cluster and migrate to it). Given the explanation of the problem, I have no clear way to diagnose the issue in existence, and equally no way to validate any proposed solution. Our workaround in the meantime has been a rough-edge delay on startup that is far from perfect, but seems to work in theory.

My job is to handle server provisioning (using Puppet) in a manner that will guarantee that this situation does not occur (if indeed it is a problem).

So my question is multi-part:

1. Does anyone know the background on why it is precisely two minutes, or have documentation from DataStax (or otherwise) to clarify the precise problems caused.
2. Has anyone in the DevOps world worked around this (using Chef/Puppet/other tools) in order to prevent this from occurring (and what did you do?)
3. Is anyone aware of a way to detect when this issue has occurred (so I can test solutions)?
4. Is anyone aware of a way to prevent this from occurring (or a way to see if a node is presently joining, and thus know you must wait)?
5. Is there someone out there that can definitively show why this delay isn't necessary? (That would make my job easier, but I assume this is unlikely).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2434 for the 'why a delay'. Shouldn't it be suffcient to monitor the new node's state with nodetool to decide when to go on (state: joining)?

Comment: My understanding (and I am not familiar with Cassandra beyond the research I've done to handle this task) is that the servers have to be brought up (service started) in sequence, and if I was using nodetool to monitor I still would have no guarantee that another node didn't attempt to spin up at the same time.
However, from your note, it sounds like I can start the service without it joining, and wait until no other boxes are joining, and trigger the join then. (Sounds vaguely possible from other things I've read). Would that be the better route to go here? (I assume nodetool ring to monitor)

Comment: Are you using vnodes?

Comment: I am honestly not sure, as I'm handling getting Cassandra installed and running with Puppet, and I do not know how the actual users will be utilizing it once it's up. So I suppose the best answer would be: Both yes and no, depending on choices that would not be in my control.

Answer (score 0):

I had a discussion with a representative from DataStax yesterday, which resulted in what I find to be a satisfactory answer.

The reasoning for the two minute wait is that when multiple boxes spin up simultaneously you can (and likely will) end up with an unbalanced distribution of data (some nodes get more load than others) which will not happen if they wait in sequence. You can also end up with inconsistencies caused by nodes not realizing they are no longer responsible for segments of data. The data responsibility can be fixed by re-assigning tokens (manually), and the inconsistency can be fixed easily by running 'nodetool repair -pr' or just 'nodetool repair' on EVERY node in the ring. This corrects for who is responsible for what, and puts the data where it needs to be.

Another option, when spinning up boxes, is to keep auto_bootstrap = false, and join the new nodes to the cluster manually (or with automated tools later on).

So, the issue that was reported to me was a bit incorrect, and the only true problem was that inconsistency can be caused, and is totally fixable.

Thanks for the responses, and I hope this helps someone else.